# CAkePHP ajax pagination issue with firefox

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am using Js Pagination in cakePHP 2.0. I have to manage search result with cakePHP pagination. For this i have set a $separator array in controller file and pass that in ctp file there

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('update' => '#mid_cont',
         'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', "cond" =>  separator),
            'before' => $this->Js->get("#loading")->effect('fadeIn'),
            'success' => $this->Js->get("#loading")->effect('fadeOut'),
        ));
```

**It is working fine in IE and chrome but not in firefox.In firefox I am getting $this->request->params array as given below:**

```
[plugin] => 
    [controller] => users
    [action] => index
    [named] => Array
        (
           [cond%5Bgender%5D] => 'Male', 
           [cond%5Bage%5D] => '18', 
        )
```

**it should be like given below`enter code here**

```
[plugin] => 
    [controller] => users
    [action] => index
    [named] => Array
        (
           [cond][gender] => 'Male', 
           [cond][age] => '18', 
        )
```

If any one know any solution or any advice related to this problem . Please help me.
    Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the parameters and it should be fine :

```
// writing
$this->params['named']['cond'] = base64_encode(json_encode($cond));
$this->params['named']['cond'] = strtr($this->params['named']['cond'], '+/=', '-_,');

// Reading
$cond = strtr($this->params['named']['cond'], '-_,', '+/=');
$cond = json_decode(base64_decode($cond), true);
```

Comment: @user525090 You can then validate this answer. Thanks ;)